# Inserting a pagedlist into room db

Tags: android

I'm implementing paging library with room db and coroutines , the part of loading data and handling all paging library methods is done , now i'm facing an issue which is  to save the data into room db , i'm actually getting a pagedlist response from api and updating adapter with it ,and since im getting pagedlist ,i need to insert it into room db so that i can  show data later in offline mode but i tried so and it didn't work , no data is showing , not sure if it is the right way to do it .

- This is my response from api

```
 mainViewModel.getAll(query,Utils().API_KEY,1).observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            newsAdapter.submitList(it)  //pagedlist 
            recyclerView.adapter = newsAdapter    
        })
```

- here is my dao

```
@Dao
interface NewsDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM news_table")
    fun restoreNews() : androidx.paging.DataSource.Factory<Int,AllNewsModel>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun storeNews(pagedList: PagedList<AllNewsModel>)

}
```

what i want to achieve is basically inserting the data of the pagedlist into my db so that i can use it to update my adapter in offline mode , thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the best approach is to do what you want to do in your repository/boundarycallback class.

You can check this repo from google.
https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-paging
It is a repo from a google codelab, that you can find it here
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-paging/#1

You can see that class inside boundarycallback that does the job at the same time it gets the answer from the Api:

```
    private fun requestAndSaveData(query: String) {
        if (isRequestInProgress) return

        isRequestInProgress = true
        searchRepos(service, query, lastRequestedPage, NETWORK_PAGE_SIZE, { repos ->
            cache.insert(repos) {
                lastRequestedPage++
                isRequestInProgress = false
            }
        }, { error ->
            _networkErrors.postValue(error)
            isRequestInProgress = false
        })
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but the example provided by codelabs got me little confused

Comment: Can you update your question with your repository/retrofit/viewmode code? It may be easier to help.

Comment: i solved it buddy , thank you so much , your answer guided me to solve it

Comment: @Taki how do you solved it